# Azure functions - Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 120000 MILLISECONDS on connecting with cosmos client

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks

Trying to connect to cosmos database using:

```
CosmosClient client =
      new CosmosClientBuilder()
          .endpoint("endpoint")
          .key("key")
          .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL)
          .buildClient();
```

While connecting getting error of : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 120000 MILLISECONDS

Comment: Which Java SDK version are you using?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I am getting the same error. I am using Spring Data Cosmos 3.2.0 which used Cosmos Java SDK v4.
sar, have you got the fix?

Comment: I changed the way to initialize  the client as singleton pattern

Comment: hello @sar, would you mind provide more details about how to make it to work? Having the same issue here. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue and adding preferredRegions to settings of CosmosClient helped.

Answer (score 0):

Add `preferredRegions` to the settings of CosmosClientBuilder.

Comment: We are facing the same issue as well and adding preferredRegions also didn't help.. Any other option we can try to resolve this issue?